# How do i position text below image

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and HTML, and I am having a little problem positioning text below an image.

As you can see below the text is positioned on the side of the image and I don't know how to fix it.

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
.section1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin: 25px;
  /* background-color: #000; */
  height: auto;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.section1 img {
  width: 20%;
  object-fit: ;
}

imagetextlink {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="section1">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" alt="test pic">
  <a class="Imagetextlink">Testtext</a>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" alt="test pic">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" alt="test pic">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" alt="test pic">
</div>
```

Comment: Images are inline elements. You need to add structural elements or change the display property to get them to behave differently. Avoid absolute positioning. Thar be dragons.

Comment: Have you tried flex-direction: column; ? Also you have a typo in your CSS + HTML: class .imagetextlink without the '. ' and in HTML starting with capital letter.

Comment: As @isherwood says, images are inline by default. Read up on [the box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model).

Comment: Check out [figure and figcaption](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figure.asp) too

Comment: Please _revise_ to make that more clear. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<image src="https://ibb.co/Mn5cc5K">
<br/>
<p>
Texest
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Use The `<br/>` Tag To Make The Text Go Below The Image.

Comment: that has only 1 image and 1 text. letting you know.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done.

```css
.section1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin: 25px;
  /* background-color: #000; */
  height: auto;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img-container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.section1 img {
  width:80px; /* change according to your need */
  height:80px; /* change according to your need */
  object-fit: ;
}
```

```html
<div class="section1">
 <div class="img-container">
   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" alt="test pic">
  <a class="Imagetextlink">Testtext</a>
 </div> 
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" alt="test pic">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" alt="test pic">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" alt="test pic">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> `<a class="Imagetextlink">Testtext</a>`

> ```css
> imagetextlink {
>   position: absolute;
> }
> ```

The problem here is, that you are

1. using the class name `imagetextlink` starting with an uppercase letter `I` in the HTML, while it starts with a lowercase letter `i` in the CSS selector
2. you forgot to put a dot `.` in front of the class name in the CSS selector. Right now, you are selecting HTML elements with **the tag name `ìmagetextlink`** instead of HTML elements whose **class name is `imagetextlink`**. The dot will fix this; read more about this [on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp).

```css
.section1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin: 25px;
  /* background-color: #000; */
  height: auto;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.section1 img {
  width: 20%;
  object-fit: ;
}

.imagetextlink {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="section1">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" alt="test pic">
  <a class="imagetextlink">Testtext</a>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" alt="test pic">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" alt="test pic">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" alt="test pic">
</div>
```